# Access form elements after reading docx with PHPWord

Tags: php, phpword

I created a docx file with PHPword and it works perfectly.
Now I have another php file where I need to read the docx file.

```
<?php
require_once 'PHPWord/bootstrap.php';

$phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createReader('Word2007')->load('helloWorld.docx');

foreach($phpWord->getSections() as $section) {
    foreach($section->getElements() as $element) {
        if(method_exists($element,'getText')) {
            print_r($element->getText());
        }
    }
}
```

This prints out an array like so:

```
Array
(
    [0] => {FORMTEXT}
)
Array
(
    [0] => {FORMCHECKBOX}
)
Array
(
    [0] => {FORMCHECKBOX}
)
```

My question is how can I access the `{FORMCHECKBOX}` and get the value of it?

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this? I have the same issue